# How to create a tree menu structure in QML Qt Quick?

Tags: qml, qt-quick

[Like this image in QML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKuy5.png)

I want to create a tree menu in QML. How to do that in QML?

Comment: Ehmm ... maybe [TreeView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qml-qtquick-controls-treeview.html)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will look into that